# BigQuery ML model evaluate keeps returning null

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

Basically, title. I am trying to query an evaluation for an TimeSeries ARIMA ML model I made. BigQuery has a [designated function to do this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-evaluate#mlevaluate_with_a_custom_threshold_and_input_data.). After training the model and using it to make a 30 day forecast, I run the ML.EVALUATE query, but everytime I do it only returns null instead of the desired accuracy measures.

After training a timeseries model
Here is the query I'm running specifically:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ML.EVALUATE(MODEL `mydataset.my_arima_model`,
    (
    SELECT
      timeseries_date,
      timeseries_metric
    FROM
      `mydataset.mytable`),
    STRUCT(TRUE AS perform_aggregation, 30 AS horizon))
```

Where `mydataset.my_arima_model` is my model, `mydataset.mytable` is the training data, and the `metric` and `date` fields are set correctly. The query is successful, and a temporary table is returned, but all fields which should contain the error measures are null. Am I doing something wrong? Should I put something else instead of the training data for `mytable`? I tried to run an evaluation on different models, including some I trained on test data I grabbed from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Returning NULL is expected in your case. The evaluation metrics are computed based on the difference between the forecasted values and the ground truth values. In your query, the ground truth values are from mydataset.mytable, which has no overlap with the forecasted values w.r.t timestampes. That is why NULL is returned. To give an example, suppose mydataset.mytable has a time series from Jan/1/2022 to June/1/2022. You need to use for example, Jan/1 to May/1, as training data in CREATE MODEL query. Then use the same ML.EVALUATE query. This compares the forecasted value and ground truth value in the whole June.